# UPDATE ANOTHER COLUMN IN AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER

Tags: postgresql, database-trigger

I have a table with three columns: id, date and dateDekete

I try to execute an update on the column dateDelete after an update on another column (column date) using a AFTER UPDATE TRIGGER.
The code that I use to create my trigger is the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_delete_date_allocation()
  RETURNS trigger LANGUAGE plpgsql AS  $body$
    BEGIN
        NEW."dateDelete" := NEW.date + 1;
        RETURN NEW;
      END;
 $body$;

CREATE TRIGGER delete_date_allocation_trg
    AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE ON client.client_portfolio_allocation
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_delete_date_allocation();
```

Although the code executes fine with no error message, the latter column that I try to update does not change.

I was wondering if it's possible to do this. AND if so, what should I change in my code?

I am using Postgres 11.5.

Answer (score 0):

you can't change the new record in an AFTER trigger, you need to declare your trigger as a BEFORE trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER delete_date_allocation_trg
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON client.client_portfolio_allocation
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_delete_date_allocation();
```

Comment: Thx for your response. Actually I need it to be done after the update. I have a list of conditions that I check depending on the date column value.

Comment: You can **not** change the `new` row in an AFTER trigger. If you want to abort the insert or update if the checks fail, you can also do that in a BEFORE trigger.

Comment: I think you are misinterpreting what BEFORE and AFTER means. Both are part to the statement itself. That can,in short form, be broken down to: Initiate DML process, perform before statement triggers, for each row: perform before row trigger, perform final data merge and constraint validation, perform after row triggers, perform after statement triggers, terminate DML statement. Any step can send execution to terminate DML.  After and Before refer not to the statement but data merge and validation step.  That is why you **cannot** change data content in an After trigger, it would NOT validated.

Comment: Oh alright. My bad then. I tried with the BEFORE and it worked. Thank you for your help.